# Dispatch the action which was underway when Access Token got expired in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux, frontend, redux-toolkit

**`AxiosInstance.js`**

```js
    instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => { return response; }, async (error) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
    
        if (error.response !== null) {
            if (error.response.status === 403 && !originalRequest._retry) {
                if (!calledOnce) {
                    calledOnce = true;
    
                    try {
                        const refreshData = await instance.get('/refresh_token/verify');
    
                        if (refreshData) {
                            const { user } = store.getState().auth;
    
                            axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${refreshData.data.access_token}`;
    
                            store.dispatch(setCredentials({
                                user,
                                accessToken: refreshData.data.access_token
                            }));
    
// --------------> Here is the API call that is made again after token is refreshed to whichever call was underway
                            return instance(originalRequest);
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        if (error.response && error.response.data) {
                            return Promise.reject(error.response.data);
                        }
    
                        return Promise.reject(error);
                    } finally {
                        originalRequest._retry = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

> What this code is doing. Its an implementation of refresh tokens functionality that makes a new call after `Access Token` gets expired and `Refresh token` from the cookie makes a new call for new `Access Token` and the call which was made from the client side (OR from Dispatched redux action) gets made again successfully.

I left a comment in above code that needs help. It is making the API call correctly but I am using Redux Toolkit in my project and Dispatch() for every single API call to keep data in Redux store. Now Here is the scenario I'm facing:

Lets suppose my `Access Token` is expired after sometime and I make a dispatch(someAction()) call. Now call returns `400` and call is made for `Refresh Token` for latest `Access Token` and original Request (`instance(originalRequest);`) is made again. The issue is I won't get the data in my Store because its not a `dispatch(someAction())` call. Its just a Network call.

But I want this to be dispatch(someAction()) which was underway to put response in my store.

> This AxiosInstance is used throughout the app for every single call. It is the core default settings.